# Server sends RST during TLS handshake. Why?

Tags: tls

I have a problem with a machine to machine communication where for me it looks like our server hangs up the TCP during the handshake, but I cannot understand why.
We have been running for several month on same setup of certificates etc. 
Our client has supposedly only changed the requirement to not support SSLv2.
But that is no problem for our server.

Is there anyone who have any idea of what is going on?
Is there any info you would like for me to provide?

Below is the TCP conversation taken from Network Monitor:

```
server  client  TCP: [Bad CheckSum]Flags=.E.A..S., SrcPort=HTTPS(443), DstPort=42262, PayloadLen=0, Seq=1989100423, Ack=2540094201, Win=8192 ( Negotiated scale factor 0x8 ) = 8192
client  server  TCP:Flags=...A...., SrcPort=42262, DstPort=HTTPS(443), PayloadLen=0, Seq=2540094201, Ack=1989100424, Win=23
client  server  TLS:TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake: Client Hello.
server  client  TCP: [Bad CheckSum]Flags=...A...., SrcPort=HTTPS(443), DstPort=42262, PayloadLen=0, Seq=1989100424, Ack=2540094357, Win=2081 (scale factor 0x0) = 2081
server  client  TLS:TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake: Server Hello. Certificate. Server Key Exchange. Server Hello Done.
client  server  TCP:Flags=...A...., SrcPort=42262, DstPort=HTTPS(443), PayloadLen=0, Seq=2540094357, Ack=1989101872, Win=35
client  server  TCP:Flags=...A...., SrcPort=42262, DstPort=HTTPS(443), PayloadLen=0, Seq=2540094357, Ack=1989103320, Win=46
client  server  TCP:Flags=...A...., SrcPort=42262, DstPort=HTTPS(443), PayloadLen=0, Seq=2540094357, Ack=1989103820, Win=57
client  server  TLS:TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake: Client Key Exchange.; TLS Rec Layer-2 Cipher Change Spec; TLS Rec Layer-3 HandShake: Encrypted Handshake Message.
server  client  TCP: [Bad CheckSum]Flags=...A.R.., SrcPort=HTTPS(443), DstPort=42262, PayloadLen=0, Seq=1989103820, Ack=2540094547, Win=0 (scale factor 0x0) = 0
```

**EDIT: 2014.11.12 - Added more details**

Below I have included detailed TCP and TLS prtocol information for each frame below.

And to provide some more information, this solution is integration applications commuicating over with SOAP over TLS. This has been all working fine until several updates was done on the client side. What exactly I have not been able to get full information about, this is a government client side...
But every SOAP request from their side ends now before the TLS handshake is done, in the exact manner each time.
I have no possibility to try out different configurations of server/client for this issue as suggested.

```
36962   18:15:51 09.12.2014 2914.4460297     (0)    Server IP   Client IP   TCP TCP: [Bad CheckSum]Flags=.E.A..S., SrcPort=HTTPS(443), DstPort=42262, PayloadLen=0, Seq=1989100423, Ack=2540094201, Win=8192 ( Negotiated scale factor 0x8 ) = 8192
    - Tcp:  [Bad CheckSum]Flags=.E.A..S., SrcPort=HTTPS(443), DstPort=42262, PayloadLen=0, Seq=1989100423, Ack=2540094201, Win=8192 ( Negotiated scale factor 0x8 ) = 8192
        SrcPort: HTTPS(443)
        DstPort: 42262
        SequenceNumber: 1989100423 (0x768F4387)
        AcknowledgementNumber: 2540094201 (0x9766C2F9)
      - DataOffset: 160 (0xA0)
         DataOffset: (1010....) 40 bytes
         Reserved:   (....000.)
         NS:         (.......0) Nonce Sum not significant
      - Flags: .E.A..S.
         CWR:    (0.......) CWR not significant
         ECE:    (.1......) ECN-Echo significant
         Urgent: (..0.....) Not Urgent Data
         Ack:    (...1....) Acknowledgement field significant
         Push:   (....0...) No Push Function
         Reset:  (.....0..) No Reset
         Syn:    (......1.) Synchronize sequence numbers
         Fin:    (.......0) Not End of data
        Window: 8192 ( Negotiated scale factor 0x8 ) = 8192
        Checksum: 0xEDDA, Bad
        UrgentPointer: 0 (0x0)
      - TCPOptions: 
       - MaxSegmentSize: 1
          type: Maximum Segment Size. 2(0x2)
          OptionLength: 4 (0x4)
          MaxSegmentSize: 1460 (0x5B4)
       - NoOption: 
          type: No operation. 1(0x1)
       - WindowsScaleFactor: ShiftCount: 8
          type: Window scale factor. 3(0x3)
          Length: 3 (0x3)
          ShiftCount: 8 (0x8)
       - SACKPermitted: 
          type: SACK permitted. 4(0x4)
          OptionLength: 2 (0x2)
       - TimeStamp: 
          type: Timestamp. 8(0x8)
          Length: 10 (0xA)
          TimestampValue: 1421864 (0x15B228)
          TimestampEchoReply: 86050255 (0x52105CF)

36963   18:15:51 09.12.2014 2914.4487184     (0)    Client IP   Server IP   TCP TCP:Flags=...A...., SrcPort=42262, DstPort=HTTPS(443), PayloadLen=0, Seq=2540094201, Ack=1989100424, Win=23 
    - Tcp: Flags=...A...., SrcPort=42262, DstPort=HTTPS(443), PayloadLen=0, Seq=2540094201, Ack=1989100424, Win=23
        SrcPort: 42262
        DstPort: HTTPS(443)
        SequenceNumber: 2540094201 (0x9766C2F9)
        AcknowledgementNumber: 1989100424 (0x768F4388)
      - DataOffset: 128 (0x80)
         DataOffset: (1000....) 32 bytes
         Reserved:   (....000.)
         NS:         (.......0) Nonce Sum not significant
      - Flags: ...A....
         CWR:    (0.......) CWR not significant
         ECE:    (.0......) ECN-Echo not significant
         Urgent: (..0.....) Not Urgent Data
         Ack:    (...1....) Acknowledgement field significant
         Push:   (....0...) No Push Function
         Reset:  (.....0..) No Reset
         Syn:    (......0.) Not Synchronize sequence numbers
         Fin:    (.......0) Not End of data
        Window: 23
        Checksum: 0x1082, Good
        UrgentPointer: 0 (0x0)
      - TCPOptions: 
       - NoOption: 
          type: No operation. 1(0x1)
       - NoOption: 
          type: No operation. 1(0x1)
       - TimeStamp: 
          type: Timestamp. 8(0x8)
          Length: 10 (0xA)
          TimestampValue: 86050256 (0x52105D0)
          TimestampEchoReply: 1421864 (0x15B228)

36969   18:15:51 09.12.2014 2914.4491115     (0)    Client IP   Server IP   TLS TLS:TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake: Client Hello.
    - Tcp: Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=42262, DstPort=HTTPS(443), PayloadLen=156, Seq=2540094201 - 2540094357, Ack=1989100424, Win=23
        SrcPort: 42262
        DstPort: HTTPS(443)
        SequenceNumber: 2540094201 (0x9766C2F9)
        AcknowledgementNumber: 1989100424 (0x768F4388)
      - DataOffset: 128 (0x80)
         DataOffset: (1000....) 32 bytes
         Reserved:   (....000.)
         NS:         (.......0) Nonce Sum not significant
      - Flags: ...AP...
         CWR:    (0.......) CWR not significant
         ECE:    (.0......) ECN-Echo not significant
         Urgent: (..0.....) Not Urgent Data
         Ack:    (...1....) Acknowledgement field significant
         Push:   (....1...) Push Function
         Reset:  (.....0..) No Reset
         Syn:    (......0.) Not Synchronize sequence numbers
         Fin:    (.......0) Not End of data
        Window: 23
        Checksum: 0xEBA1, Good
        UrgentPointer: 0 (0x0)
      - TCPOptions: 
       - NoOption: 
          type: No operation. 1(0x1)
       - NoOption: 
          type: No operation. 1(0x1)
       - TimeStamp: 
          type: Timestamp. 8(0x8)
          Length: 10 (0xA)
          TimestampValue: 86050256 (0x52105D0)
          TimestampEchoReply: 1421864 (0x15B228)
        TCPPayload: SourcePort = 42262, DestinationPort = 443
      TLSSSLData: Transport Layer Security (TLS) Payload Data
    - TLS: TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake: Client Hello.
      - TlsRecordLayer: TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake:
         ContentType: HandShake:
       - Version: TLS 1.0
          Major: 3 (0x3)
          Minor: 1 (0x1)
         Length: 151 (0x97)
       - SSLHandshake: SSL HandShake ClientHello(0x01)
          HandShakeType: ClientHello(0x01)
          Length: 147 (0x93)
        - ClientHello: TLS 1.2
         - Version: TLS 1.2
            Major: 3 (0x3)
            Minor: 3 (0x3)
         - RandomBytes: 
            TimeStamp: 12/09/2014, 17:15:52 .0000 UTC 
            RandomBytes: Binary Large Object (28 Bytes)
           SessionIDLength: 0 (0x0)
           CipherSuitesLength: 78
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384     { 0x00, 0xA3 }
            Cipher: 163 (0xA3)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384     { 0x00, 0x9F }
            Cipher: 159 (0x9F)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256     { 0x00, 0x6B }
            Cipher: 107 (0x6B)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256     { 0x00, 0x6A }
            Cipher: 106 (0x6A)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA        { 0x00, 0x39 }
            Cipher: 57 (0x39)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA        { 0x00, 0x38 }
            Cipher: 56 (0x38)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384       { 0x00, 0x9D }
            Cipher: 157 (0x9D)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256         { 0x00, 0x3D }
            Cipher: 61 (0x3D)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA            { 0x00, 0x35 }
            Cipher: 53 (0x35)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA        { 0x00,0x16}
            Cipher: 22 (0x16)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA        { 0x00,0x13 }
            Cipher: 19 (0x13)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA           { 0x00,0x0A }
            Cipher: 10 (0xA)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256     { 0x00, 0xA2 }
            Cipher: 162 (0xA2)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256     { 0x00, 0x9E }
            Cipher: 158 (0x9E)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256     { 0x00, 0x67 }
            Cipher: 103 (0x67)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256     { 0x00, 0x40 }
            Cipher: 64 (0x40)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA        { 0x00, 0x33 }
            Cipher: 51 (0x33)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA        { 0x00, 0x32 }
            Cipher: 50 (0x32)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256         { 0x00, 0x9C }
            Cipher: 156 (0x9C)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256         { 0x00, 0x3C }
            Cipher: 60 (0x3C)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA            { 0x00, 0x2F }
            Cipher: 47 (0x2F)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_NTRU_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA      { 0x00, 0x66 }
            Cipher: 102 (0x66)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA                { 0x00,0x05 }
            Cipher: 5 (0x5)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5                { 0x00,0x04 }
            Cipher: 4 (0x4)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_NTRU_NSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA       { 0x00, 0x63 }
            Cipher: 99 (0x63)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA             { 0x00,0x15 }
            Cipher: 21 (0x15)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA             { 0x00,0x12 }
            Cipher: 18 (0x12)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_NTRU_NSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA      { 0x00, 0x62 }
            Cipher: 98 (0x62)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA                { 0x00,0x09 }
            Cipher: 9 (0x9)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_NTRU_NSS_WITH_RC4_128_SHA           { 0x00, 0x61 }
            Cipher: 97 (0x61)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_NTRU_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA           { 0x00, 0x65 }
            Cipher: 101 (0x65)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_NTRU_NSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA       { 0x00, 0x64 }
            Cipher: 100 (0x64)
         - TLSCipherSuites: Unknown Cipher
            Cipher: 96 (0x60)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA    { 0x00,0x14 }
            Cipher: 20 (0x14)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA   { 0x00,0x11 }
            Cipher: 17 (0x11)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA       { 0x00,0x08 }
            Cipher: 8 (0x8)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC2_CBC_40_MD5      { 0x00,0x06 }
            Cipher: 6 (0x6)
         - TLSCipherSuites: TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5          { 0x00,0x03 }
            Cipher: 3 (0x3)
         - TLSCipherSuites: Unknown Cipher
            Cipher: 255 (0xFF)
           CompressionMethodsLength: 1 (0x1)
           CompressionMethods: 0 (0x0)
           ExtensionsLength: 28 (0x1C)
         - ClientHelloExtension: Signature Algorithms(0x000D)
            ExtensionType: Signature Algorithms(0x000D)
            ExtensionLength: 24 (0x18)
            Data: Binary Large Object (24 Bytes)


36972   18:15:51 09.12.2014 2914.4512965     (0)    Server IP   Client IP   TCP TCP: [Bad CheckSum]Flags=...A...., SrcPort=HTTPS(443), DstPort=42262, PayloadLen=0, Seq=1989100424, Ack=2540094357, Win=2081 (scale factor 0x0) = 2081
    - Tcp:  [Bad CheckSum]Flags=...A...., SrcPort=HTTPS(443), DstPort=42262, PayloadLen=0, Seq=1989100424, Ack=2540094357, Win=2081 (scale factor 0x0) = 2081
        SrcPort: HTTPS(443)
        DstPort: 42262
        SequenceNumber: 1989100424 (0x768F4388)
        AcknowledgementNumber: 2540094357 (0x9766C395)
      - DataOffset: 128 (0x80)
         DataOffset: (1000....) 32 bytes
         Reserved:   (....000.)
         NS:         (.......0) Nonce Sum not significant
      - Flags: ...A....
         CWR:    (0.......) CWR not significant
         ECE:    (.0......) ECN-Echo not significant
         Urgent: (..0.....) Not Urgent Data
         Ack:    (...1....) Acknowledgement field significant
         Push:   (....0...) No Push Function
         Reset:  (.....0..) No Reset
         Syn:    (......0.) Not Synchronize sequence numbers
         Fin:    (.......0) Not End of data
        Window: 2081 (scale factor 0x0) = 2081
        Checksum: 0xEDD2, Bad
        UrgentPointer: 0 (0x0)
      - TCPOptions: 
       - NoOption: 
          type: No operation. 1(0x1)
       - NoOption: 
          type: No operation. 1(0x1)
       - TimeStamp: 
          type: Timestamp. 8(0x8)
          Length: 10 (0xA)
          TimestampValue: 1421865 (0x15B229)
          TimestampEchoReply: 86050256 (0x52105D0)


36975   18:15:51 09.12.2014 2914.4548786     (4)    Server IP   Client IP   TLS TLS:TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake: Server Hello. Certificate. Server Key Exchange. Server Hello Done.
    - Tcp:  [Bad CheckSum]Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=HTTPS(443), DstPort=42262, PayloadLen=3396, Seq=1989100424 - 1989103820, Ack=2540094357, Win=2081 (scale factor 0x0) = 2081
        SrcPort: HTTPS(443)
        DstPort: 42262
        SequenceNumber: 1989100424 (0x768F4388)
        AcknowledgementNumber: 2540094357 (0x9766C395)
      - DataOffset: 128 (0x80)
         DataOffset: (1000....) 32 bytes
         Reserved:   (....000.)
         NS:         (.......0) Nonce Sum not significant
      - Flags: ...AP...
         CWR:    (0.......) CWR not significant
         ECE:    (.0......) ECN-Echo not significant
         Urgent: (..0.....) Not Urgent Data
         Ack:    (...1....) Acknowledgement field significant
         Push:   (....1...) Push Function
         Reset:  (.....0..) No Reset
         Syn:    (......0.) Not Synchronize sequence numbers
         Fin:    (.......0) Not End of data
        Window: 2081 (scale factor 0x0) = 2081
        Checksum: 0xEDB2, Bad
        UrgentPointer: 0 (0x0)
      - TCPOptions: 
       - NoOption: 
          type: No operation. 1(0x1)
       - NoOption: 
          type: No operation. 1(0x1)
       - TimeStamp: 
          type: Timestamp. 8(0x8)
          Length: 10 (0xA)
          TimestampValue: 1421865 (0x15B229)
          TimestampEchoReply: 86050256 (0x52105D0)
        TCPPayload: SourcePort = 443, DestinationPort = 42262
      TLSSSLData: Transport Layer Security (TLS) Payload Data
    - TLS: TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake: Server Hello. Certificate. Server Key Exchange. Server Hello Done.
      - TlsRecordLayer: TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake:
         ContentType: HandShake:
       - Version: TLS 1.2
          Major: 3 (0x3)
          Minor: 3 (0x3)
         Length: 3391 (0xD3F)
       - SSLHandshake: SSL HandShake Server Hello Done(0x0E)
          HandShakeType: ServerHello(0x02)
          Length: 77 (0x4D)
        - ServerHello: 0x1
         - Version: TLS 1.2
            Major: 3 (0x3)
            Minor: 3 (0x3)
         - RandomBytes: 
            TimeStamp: 12/09/2014, 17:15:51 .0000 UTC 
            RandomBytes: Binary Large Object (28 Bytes)
           SessionIDLength: 32 (0x20)
           SessionID: Binary Large Object (32 Bytes)
           TLSCipherSuite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384     { 0x00, 0x9F }
           CompressionMethods: 0 (0x0)
           ExtensionsLength: 5 (0x5)
         - ServerHelloExtension: Renegotiation Info(0xFF01)
            ExtensionType: Renegotiation Info(0xFF01)
            ExtensionLength: 1 (0x1)
            Data: Binary Large Object (1 Bytes)
          HandShakeType: Certificate(0x0B)
          Length: 2648 (0xA58)
        - Cert: 0x1
           CertLength: 2645 (0xA55)
         + Certificates: 
         + Certificates: 
          HandShakeType: Server Key Exchange(0x0C)
          Length: 650 (0x28A)
          ServerKeyExchange: Binary Large Object (650 Bytes)
          HandShakeType: Server Hello Done(0x0E)
          Length: 0 (0x0)

36976   18:15:51 09.12.2014 2914.4577770     (0)    Client IP   Server IP   TCP TCP:Flags=...A...., SrcPort=42262, DstPort=HTTPS(443), PayloadLen=0, Seq=2540094357, Ack=1989101872, Win=35

    - Tcp: Flags=...A...., SrcPort=42262, DstPort=HTTPS(443), PayloadLen=0, Seq=2540094357, Ack=1989101872, Win=35
        SrcPort: 42262
        DstPort: HTTPS(443)
        SequenceNumber: 2540094357 (0x9766C395)
        AcknowledgementNumber: 1989101872 (0x768F4930)
      - DataOffset: 128 (0x80)
         DataOffset: (1000....) 32 bytes
         Reserved:   (....000.)
         NS:         (.......0) Nonce Sum not significant
      - Flags: ...A....
         CWR:    (0.......) CWR not significant
         ECE:    (.0......) ECN-Echo not significant
         Urgent: (..0.....) Not Urgent Data
         Ack:    (...1....) Acknowledgement field significant
         Push:   (....0...) No Push Function
         Reset:  (.....0..) No Reset
         Syn:    (......0.) Not Synchronize sequence numbers
         Fin:    (.......0) Not End of data
        Window: 35
        Checksum: 0xA2F, Good
        UrgentPointer: 0 (0x0)
      - TCPOptions: 
       - NoOption: 
          type: No operation. 1(0x1)
       - NoOption: 
          type: No operation. 1(0x1)
       - TimeStamp: 
          type: Timestamp. 8(0x8)
          Length: 10 (0xA)
          TimestampValue: 86050258 (0x52105D2)
          TimestampEchoReply: 1421865 (0x15B229)


36980   18:15:51 09.12.2014 2914.4581476     (0)    Client IP   Server IP   TCP TCP:Flags=...A...., SrcPort=42262, DstPort=HTTPS(443), PayloadLen=0, Seq=2540094357, Ack=1989103320, Win=46
    - Tcp: Flags=...A...., SrcPort=42262, DstPort=HTTPS(443), PayloadLen=0, Seq=2540094357, Ack=1989103320, Win=46
        SrcPort: 42262
        DstPort: HTTPS(443)
        SequenceNumber: 2540094357 (0x9766C395)
        AcknowledgementNumber: 1989103320 (0x768F4ED8)
      - DataOffset: 128 (0x80)
         DataOffset: (1000....) 32 bytes
         Reserved:   (....000.)
         NS:         (.......0) Nonce Sum not significant
      - Flags: ...A....
         CWR:    (0.......) CWR not significant
         ECE:    (.0......) ECN-Echo not significant
         Urgent: (..0.....) Not Urgent Data
         Ack:    (...1....) Acknowledgement field significant
         Push:   (....0...) No Push Function
         Reset:  (.....0..) No Reset
         Syn:    (......0.) Not Synchronize sequence numbers
         Fin:    (.......0) Not End of data
        Window: 46
        Checksum: 0x47C, Good
        UrgentPointer: 0 (0x0)
      - TCPOptions: 
       - NoOption: 
          type: No operation. 1(0x1)
       - NoOption: 
          type: No operation. 1(0x1)
       - TimeStamp: 
          type: Timestamp. 8(0x8)
          Length: 10 (0xA)
          TimestampValue: 86050258 (0x52105D2)
          TimestampEchoReply: 1421865 (0x15B229)

36983   18:15:51 09.12.2014 2914.4582581     (0)    Client IP   Server IP   TCP TCP:Flags=...A...., SrcPort=42262, DstPort=HTTPS(443), PayloadLen=0, Seq=2540094357, Ack=1989103820, Win=57

    - Tcp: Flags=...A...., SrcPort=42262, DstPort=HTTPS(443), PayloadLen=0, Seq=2540094357, Ack=1989103820, Win=57
        SrcPort: 42262
        DstPort: HTTPS(443)
        SequenceNumber: 2540094357 (0x9766C395)
        AcknowledgementNumber: 1989103820 (0x768F50CC)
      - DataOffset: 128 (0x80)
         DataOffset: (1000....) 32 bytes
         Reserved:   (....000.)
         NS:         (.......0) Nonce Sum not significant
      - Flags: ...A....
         CWR:    (0.......) CWR not significant
         ECE:    (.0......) ECN-Echo not significant
         Urgent: (..0.....) Not Urgent Data
         Ack:    (...1....) Acknowledgement field significant
         Push:   (....0...) No Push Function
         Reset:  (.....0..) No Reset
         Syn:    (......0.) Not Synchronize sequence numbers
         Fin:    (.......0) Not End of data
        Window: 57
        Checksum: 0x27D, Good
        UrgentPointer: 0 (0x0)
      - TCPOptions: 
       - NoOption: 
          type: No operation. 1(0x1)
       - NoOption: 
          type: No operation. 1(0x1)
       - TimeStamp: 
          type: Timestamp. 8(0x8)
          Length: 10 (0xA)
          TimestampValue: 86050258 (0x52105D2)
          TimestampEchoReply: 1421865 (0x15B229)

36987   18:15:51 09.12.2014 2914.4613152     (0)    Client IP   Server IP   TLS TLS:TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake: Client Key Exchange.; TLS Rec Layer-2 Cipher Change Spec; TLS Rec Layer-3 HandShake: Encrypted Handshake Message.
    - Tcp: Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=42262, DstPort=HTTPS(443), PayloadLen=190, Seq=2540094357 - 2540094547, Ack=1989103820, Win=57
        SrcPort: 42262
        DstPort: HTTPS(443)
        SequenceNumber: 2540094357 (0x9766C395)
        AcknowledgementNumber: 1989103820 (0x768F50CC)
      - DataOffset: 128 (0x80)
         DataOffset: (1000....) 32 bytes
         Reserved:   (....000.)
         NS:         (.......0) Nonce Sum not significant
      - Flags: ...AP...
         CWR:    (0.......) CWR not significant
         ECE:    (.0......) ECN-Echo not significant
         Urgent: (..0.....) Not Urgent Data
         Ack:    (...1....) Acknowledgement field significant
         Push:   (....1...) Push Function
         Reset:  (.....0..) No Reset
         Syn:    (......0.) Not Synchronize sequence numbers
         Fin:    (.......0) Not End of data
        Window: 57
        Checksum: 0x63CB, Good
        UrgentPointer: 0 (0x0)
      - TCPOptions: 
       - NoOption: 
          type: No operation. 1(0x1)
       - NoOption: 
          type: No operation. 1(0x1)
       - TimeStamp: 
          type: Timestamp. 8(0x8)
          Length: 10 (0xA)
          TimestampValue: 86050259 (0x52105D3)
          TimestampEchoReply: 1421865 (0x15B229)
        TCPPayload: SourcePort = 42262, DestinationPort = 443
      TLSSSLData: Transport Layer Security (TLS) Payload Data
    - TLS: TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake: Client Key Exchange.; TLS Rec Layer-2 Cipher Change Spec; TLS Rec Layer-3 HandShake: Encrypted Handshake Message.
      - TlsRecordLayer: TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake:
         ContentType: HandShake:
       - Version: TLS 1.2
          Major: 3 (0x3)
          Minor: 3 (0x3)
         Length: 134 (0x86)
       - SSLHandshake: SSL HandShake Client Key Exchange(0x10)
          HandShakeType: Client Key Exchange(0x10)
          Length: 130 (0x82)
          ClientKeyExchange: Binary Large Object (130 Bytes)
      - TlsRecordLayer: TLS Rec Layer-2 Cipher Change Spec
         ContentType: Cipher Change Spec
       - Version: TLS 1.2
          Major: 3 (0x3)
          Minor: 3 (0x3)
         Length: 1 (0x1)
       - ChangeCipherSpec: 0x1
          ChangeCipherSpecValue: 1 (0x1)
      - TlsRecordLayer: TLS Rec Layer-3 HandShake:
         ContentType: HandShake:
       - Version: TLS 1.2
          Major: 3 (0x3)
          Minor: 3 (0x3)
         Length: 40 (0x28)
       - SSLHandshake: SSL HandShake Client Key Exchange(0x10)
          EncryptedHandshakeMessage: Binary Large Object (40 Bytes)

36993   18:15:51 09.12.2014 2914.4634018     (4)    Server IP   Client IP   TCP TCP: [Bad CheckSum]Flags=...A.R.., SrcPort=HTTPS(443), DstPort=42262, PayloadLen=0, Seq=1989103820, Ack=2540094547, Win=0 (scale factor 0x0) = 0
    - Tcp:  [Bad CheckSum]Flags=...A.R.., SrcPort=HTTPS(443), DstPort=42262, PayloadLen=0, Seq=1989103820, Ack=2540094547, Win=0 (scale factor 0x0) = 0
        SrcPort: HTTPS(443)
        DstPort: 42262
        SequenceNumber: 1989103820 (0x768F50CC)
        AcknowledgementNumber: 2540094547 (0x9766C453)
      - DataOffset: 80 (0x50)
         DataOffset: (0101....) 20 bytes
         Reserved:   (....000.)
         NS:         (.......0) Nonce Sum not significant
      - Flags: ...A.R..
         CWR:    (0.......) CWR not significant
         ECE:    (.0......) ECN-Echo not significant
         Urgent: (..0.....) Not Urgent Data
         Ack:    (...1....) Acknowledgement field significant
         Push:   (....0...) No Push Function
         Reset:  (.....1..) Reset
         Syn:    (......0.) Not Synchronize sequence numbers
         Fin:    (.......0) Not End of data
        Window: 0 (scale factor 0x0) = 0
        Checksum: 0xEDC6, Bad
        UrgentPointer: 0 (0x0)
```

**EDIT: 2014.12.12 problem solved**

The actual problem was due to a a securitypatch from MS (https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2992611). And the client side had changed from having TLS1.0 as default preferred to TLS1.2. With the above mentioned patch from MS it work ok to communicate with TLS1.0, but not TLS1.1 or TLS1.2.
The final solution was to disable usage of these new ciphers on our server side.
Now both parties speak happily together over TLS1.2.

Thanks all for your time.

Regards

Roy

Comment: For some reason the checksum of the key exchange that is provided in the Encrypted Handshake message is wrong.  That's the problem, I'm sorry I don't know the answer.

Comment: No, this is in fact a result of checksumvalidattion is handed over to the hardware. See here http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/243294

Comment: Ah I didn't realize it wasn't part of the TLS.  This is all you have to go on?  I imagine the httpd logs would give some better visibility into the issue.  Or are you not on the server side?

Comment: I am on the serverside but this communication never reaches the http logs for iis. It has ended before this.

Comment: These are to few information for debugging the problem. A real packet capture (cloudshark or similar) might be needed. Please test also with other client/server combinations to narrow the problem down to the client or the server.

Comment: I've tried to provide some more information and a lot more details of the actual TCP/TLS data in the above mentioned TCP trace. I hope this will be of any help.

Comment: Instead of editing your question, write a answer and check it as one ;)